# Lua: dynamically determine if object is "class" or "instance"

Tags: python, lua

I am doing a remote procedure call from another language where I do not know whether the Lua function I am calling is a 'class' or 'member' function. This is important because I need to know whether to pass in `self` as an argument. Is there a way to determine whether the function I am calling is a member function or class function?

**Lua Server**

```
function obj.get_sum(a, b, c)
    return a + b + c
end
function obj:get_name()
    return self.name
end
```

**Python Client**

```
objClass.get_sum(1, 2, 3)
objInstance.get_name()
```

In the case of `objInstance.get_name()`, I need to pass `self` as an argument to the Lua function.

Comment: @idjaw, unfortunately, I don't have the classes implemented on the Python side, the implementation lies on the Lua side and the functions are used through RPC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no difference between functions in Lua.

It could be stored in a 'class', or it could be global function, or 'class member' function could be copied into local variable - there's no way to determine if function is a part of a class or a free function, because there's no classes in Lua. You can construct a system that behaves just like class system, but it's not the class in the Java/C++ meaning. You can call that function on any other unrelated table, and it will work just fine, provided all needed data is found in that table.

You can make a guess by looking at function's first local variable with `debug.getlocal()`, as arguments counts as local variables. If you see "self" as a name - there's a chance that this function was declared with colon syntax (`function obj:method()`), but that's just a syntactic sugar for explicit `function obj.method(self)` declaration, and not a guarantee for function-class relations. Even if you get "self" as first argument, it could be a free function with first argument named "self", or "member" function was declared with dot syntax and explicit "self" argument. You may not see "self" argument in a "member" function if it was declared with dot syntax and some other name for object to run on, or `debug.getlocal()` may even fail to find argument name because Lua source file was precompiled into bytecode with debug info stripped out.

For example:

```
-- "free" function that is not related to any class
local generic_func = function(table, x)
    return table.pos + x
end

-- object of some class
local obj = { pos = 1}

-- some unrelated table with "pos" element of string type
local unrelated = { pos = "42" }

-- define "method" with colon syntax, implicit "self" argument
function obj:func1(x)
    return self.pos + x
end

-- define "method" with dot syntax, explicitly naming first argument
function obj.func2(object, x)
    -- no "self" at all
    return object.pos + x
end

-- put a "free function" in a "class"
obj.func3 = generic_func

-- identical results, no matter how you call it
print(obj:func1(2))
print(obj.func1(obj, 2))
print(obj:func2(2))
print(obj.func2(obj, 2))
print(obj:func3(2))
print(obj.func3(obj, 2))
print(generic_func(obj, 2))

-- "method" function from "obj" runs on unrelated table
print(obj.func1(unrelated, 2))
```

See here: http://ideone.com/qRby6s